# Cannot find a recipe for grpcio and firebase-admin for kivy-ios or python-for-android

Tags: python, kivy, firebase-admin, python-for-android

Does anyone know a recipe for grpcio and firebase-admin on kivy-ios?

Thanks for the time consideration.